# Umbraco-Images not displaying from existing HTML markup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, umbraco

not sure if many of you have used Umbraco before, the .net based CMS.
Anyway im trying to move my HTML/CSS site that i made in Dreamweaver over to Umbraco.
The live site can be found at http://www.innexdesign.co.uk

Anyway i've pretty much managed to convert this site to Umbraco with relative ease.
The only problem is the homepage. If you look at the existing homepage http://www.innexdesign.co.uk/index.html then you will notice the rollover words/images that rollover to black when hovering over them. When you click any of them a lightbox with some information appears.

On my Umbraco version nothing happens when i click any of these rollover images. Also the rollover image "Design and Build" which contains a hyperlink to an external website does not display in Umbraco for some reason.

I have used ligthboxes in other pages fine. For example go into the Design Menu and click on any bar or restaurant and a lightbox appears with information on it.

Here's the code that doesnt seem to be working in Umbraco:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/umbraco/masterpages/default.master" AutoEventWireup="true" %>



<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="ContentPlaceHolderDefault" runat="server">      
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder Id="MasterContentPlaceHolder" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html  lang="en">
<head>

<!--META DATA -->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no" />
<meta name="keywords" content=" Innex Design, design, designers warrington, interior design warrington, cheshire, northwest, manchester, liverpool, pub designers,bar designers, architect, architects, carbon neutral, design manchester, designer in warrington, architect warrington" />
<meta name="description" content=" From a house extension or housing estate, to commercial warehouses’, leisure centres and bars, Innex Design can help develop any idea into a practical, ethical, sustainable reality." />
<meta name="robots" content="index,follow" />


<!-- #BeginEditable "doctitle" -->
<title>Innex Design</title><!--Umbraco Page Field will get inserted here to dynamically change title of page-->





  <!--SCRIPTS AND STYLESHEETS -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/script.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Scripts/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" media="screen" />    
 <link rel= "stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" />


  <!--JAVASCRIPT -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

      $(".various1").fancybox({
        'titlePosition'    : 'inside',
        'transitionIn'    : 'none',
        'transitionOut'    : 'none'
      });
    });
function MM_swapImgRestore() { //v3.0
  var i,x,a=document.MM_sr; for(i=0;a&&i<a.length&&(x=a[i])&&x.oSrc;i++) x.src=x.oSrc;
}
function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
  var d=document; if(d.images){ if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array();
    var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments; for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    if (a[i].indexOf("#")!=0){ d.MM_p[j]=new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];}}
}

function MM_findObj(n, d) { //v4.01
  var p,i,x;  if(!d) d=document; if((p=n.indexOf("?"))>0&&parent.frames.length) {
    d=parent.frames[n.substring(p+1)].document; n=n.substring(0,p);}
  if(!(x=d[n])&&d.all) x=d.all[n]; for (i=0;!x&&i<d.forms.length;i++) x=d.forms[i][n];
  for(i=0;!x&&d.layers&&i<d.layers.length;i++) x=MM_findObj(n,d.layers[i].document);
  if(!x && d.getElementById) x=d.getElementById(n); return x;
}

function MM_swapImage() { //v3.0
  var i,j=0,x,a=MM_swapImage.arguments; document.MM_sr=new Array; for(i=0;i<(a.length-2);i+=3)
   if ((x=MM_findObj(a[i]))!=null){document.MM_sr[j++]=x; if(!x.oSrc) x.oSrc=x.src; x.src=a[i+2];}
}
    </script>  

  <!--CSS SCRIPT-->
<style type="text/css">
body {
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
</style>
</head>

  **<body onload="MM_preloadImages('/media/57/architectureBLACK.png','/media/446/interior-designBLACK.png','/media/732/project-managementBLACK.png','/media/253/cost-managementBLACK.png','/media/714/PlanningBLACK.png','/media/922/SurveyingBLACK.png','/media/333/energy-assessmentsBLACK.png','/media/506/landscape-architectureBLACK.png','/media/288/Design-&amp;-BuildBLACK.png')">**


  <!--DIV HEADER USED IN HOME, PROUILE AND CALLBACK PAGES ONLY-->
<div id="header">
      <div id="headerimgs">
        <div id="headerimg1" class="headerimg"></div>
        <div id="headerimg2" class="headerimg"></div>     
  </div>


<div id="logo">
    <a href="home.aspx" target="_self"><img src="/media/436/innexdesign_logo.jpg" width="143" height="206" alt="Innex Design Logo" /></a>
    </div>


  <div id="social">
    <a href="http://twitter.com/#!/InnexDesign" target="_new"><img src="/media/980/twitter.png" width="41" height="40" alt="Innex Design on Twitter" /></a>
    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/innexdesignltd" target="_new"><img src="/media/351/facebook.png" width="41" height="40" alt="Innex Design on Facebook" /></a>
         <a href="request-a-callback.aspx" title="Request a Callback" target="_new"><img src="/media/192/callback.png" alt="" width="77" height="40" /></a>
    <a href="request-a-callback.aspx" title="Leave Your Details and Sign up to our News Letter" target="_new"><img src="/media/641/Newsletter Image.png" alt="" width="77" height="40" /></a></div>
  </div>

  <!--DIV CONTENT,HOMEMENU ETC ELEMENTS ONLY USED IN HOME,PROFILE AND CALLBACK PAGES-->
<div id="content">
<div id="homeleft">
    <ul class="menu">
    <li class="first"><a href="home.aspx">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="profile.aspx">PROFILE</a></li>
    <li><a href="designs.aspx">DESIGNS</a></li>
    <li><a href="testimonials.aspx">TESTIMONIALS</a></li>    
    <li class="last"><a href="contact.aspx">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
    <p style="text-align:center; font-weight:bold;">CELEBRATING<br /><span style="font-size:22px">21</span><br />YEARS<br />1991-2012</p>
    </div>


  <div id="homeright">


<a class="various1" href="#architecture" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Architecture','','images/architectureBLACK.png',1)"><img src="images/architecture.png" alt="Architecture" width="195" height="31" id="Architecture" style="padding:0px 20px;float:left;"/></a>
 <a class="various1" href="#idesign" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('interiordesign','','images/interior-designBLACK.png',1)"><img src="images/interior-design.png" alt="Interior Design" width="195" height="31" id="interiordesign" style="padding:0px 0px 5px 20px; float:right;"/></a>
   <a class="various1" href="#pmanage" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Projman','','images/project-managementBLACK.png',1)"><img src="images/project-management.png" alt="Project Managment" width="195" height="31" id="Projman" style="padding:20px 42px 5px 20px;float:left;"/></a>
<a class="various1" href="#planning" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Planning','','images/PlanningBLACK.png',1)"><img src="images/Planning.png" alt="Planning" width="195" height="31" id="Planning" style="padding:10px 12px 5px 0px;float:right;"/></a>

  <a class="various1" href="#energy" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Energy Assessment','','images/energy-assessmentsBLACK.png',1)"><img src="images/energy-assessments.png" alt="Energy Assessments" width="195" height="31" id="EnergyAssessment" style="padding:0px 42px 0px 20px;float:right;"/></a>
  <a class="various1" href="#surveying" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Surveying','','images/SurveyingBLACK.png',1)"><img src="images/Surveying.png" alt="Surveying" width="195" height="31" id="Surveying" style="padding:10px;float:left;" /></a>
  <a class="various1" href="#cost" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('CostManagement','','images/cost-managementBLACK.png',1)"><img src="images/cost-management.png" alt="Cost Management" width="195" height="31" id="CostManagement" style="padding:0px 12px 0px 20px; float:left;"/></a>
  <a class="various1" href="#land" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('landscape','','images/landscape-architectureBLACK.png',1)"><img src="images/Landscape-Architecture.png" alt="Landscape Architecture" width="195" height="31" id="landscape" style="padding:20px 0px 0px 20px; float:right;" /></a>
      **<div id="various1"> <a href="http://www.innexdevelopments.co.uk" target="_blank"  onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('DesignBuild','','images/Design-&amp;-BuildBLACK.png',1)"><img src="images/Design-&amp;-Build.png" alt="Design &amp; Build" width="195" height="31" id="DesignBuild" style="padding:10px 0 0 0px;float:left;"/></a>
    </div>**

**<div style="display:none"><div id="architecture">
        <img src="/media/52/architecture.png" width="195" height="31" alt="Architecture" />
        <p style="padding:0px 0px 5px 0px; width:500px;">From a house extension or housing estate, to commercial warehouses’, leisure centres and bars, Innex Design can help develop any idea into a practical, ethical, sustainable reality.</p>    
    </div></div>

        <div style="display:none"><div id="idesign">
        <img src="/media/441/interior-design.png" width="195" height="31" alt="Interior Design" />
        <p style="padding:0px 0px 5px 0px; width:500px;">Innex Design’s Interior and brand development designers are experts in spatial design, brand development and awareness, signage and menu design all of which is complimented with the interior design package delivered.</p>    
        </div></div>

        <div style="display:none"><div id="pmanage">
        <img src="/media/727/project-management.png" width="195" height="31" alt="Project Management" />
        <p style="padding:0px 0px 5px 0px; width:500px;">Many of our architectural and interior design developments are project managed ensuring the brief and end aim is delivered on time and on budget. Only with project management can we ensure our clients that the specification and quality is to the highest standard.</p>
        </div></div>

        <div style="display:none"><div id="planning">
          <img src="/media/709/Planning.png" width="195" height="31" alt="Planning" />
        <p style="padding:0px 0px 5px 0px; width:500px;">Innex Design undertake all planning application submissions from residential, commercial, listed and conservation area consents, national park along with Display of Advertisement applications. We also work with planning consultants to add value for developers and lenders by assessing land and building use potential.</p>
        </div></div>

         <div style="display:none"><div id="surveying">
           <img src="/media/917/Surveying.png" width="195" height="31" alt="Surveying" />
        <p style="padding:0px 0px 5px 0px; width:500px;">Innex Design can provide a wide variety of surveys from measured and condition surveys of buildings, Topographical surveys, Structural surveys, Party Wall surveys, and provide assistance with Asbestos surveys, Land/Probate surveys, certification and many more.</p>
        </div></div>

        <div style="display:none"><div id="energy">
        <img src="/media/328/energy-assessments.png" width="195" height="31" alt="Energy Assessments" />
        <p style="padding:0px 0px 5px 0px; width:500px;">Innex Design can assist with providing full building services design and energy consultancy, and through one of our partners BREEAM assessment, Commercial EPC, Domestic EPC, Display energy certificates, New Build SAP or SBEM reports and Sustainability statements.</p>
        </div></div>

         <div style="display:none"><div id="cost">
           <img src="/media/248/cost-management.png" width="195" height="31" alt="Cost Management" />
        <p style="padding:0px 0px 5px 0px; width:500px;">Innex Design offer all clients a comprehensive service that removes the burden of day to day costs-related issues.</p>
        </div></div>

        <div style="display:none"><div id="land">
          <img src="/media/501/Landscape-Architecture.png" width="195" height="31" alt="Landscape Architecture" />
        <p style="padding:0px 0px 5px 0px; width:500px;">We undertake all aspects of landscape architecture, from landscape master planning, conceptual design through to detailed planting schemes. We adopt a fresh approach to the design of each project where a high degree of design flair and innovation comes as standard. </p>
        </div></div>

         <div style="display:none"><div id="build">
           <img src="/media/283/Design-&amp;-Build.png" width="195" height="31" alt="Design &amp; Build" />
        <p style="padding:0px 0px 5px 0px; width:500px;">In today’s industry and marketplace some clients prefer a one point of contact approach to projects, with this in mind we have developed a nationwide network of partnering contractors to enable clients to have the one point contact, whilst ensuring delivery of excellent quality and standards of workmanship.</p>
        </div></div>**
  </div>
</div><!-- end content -->
</div><!-- end wrapper -->






        <div id="logosother">
          <div class="logos"><a href="http://www.altiusva.com/ " target="_blank"><img src="/media/47/altius-logo.jpg" width="132" height="52" alt="Altius Logo" /></a> <a href="http://www.chas.gov.uk " target="_blank"><img src="/media/208/chas-logo.jpg" width="48" height="52" alt="Chas Logo" /></a> <a href="http://www.constructionline.co.uk/static/" target="_blank"><img src="/media/238/Construction line.jpg" width="48" height="52" alt="Construction Line" longdesc="http://www.constructionline.co.uk/static/" /></a> <a href="http://www.eurosafeuk.co.uk/ " target="_blank"><img src="/media/341/Eurosafe.jpg" width="48" height="52" alt="Eurosafe" longdesc="http://www.eurosafeuk.co.uk/ " /></a> <a href="http://bii.bii.org/home" target="_blank"><img src="/media/112/BII.jpg" alt="BII" width="48" height="52" longdesc="http://bii.bii.org/home" /></a> <a href="http://committedtoequality.co.uk" target="_blank"><img src="/media/233/commitedtoequality.jpg" width="43" height="50" alt="Commited To Equality" longdesc="http://committedtoequality.co.uk" /></a></div>
          <div class="carbon"><a href="/media/200/Carbon Managment Plan.pdf" target="_new"><img src="/media/203/carbon-logo.jpg" width="149" height="85" alt="Carbon Neutral Logo" /></a></div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
  <p style="float:left">Copyright &copy; 2012 - Innex Design       </p>
    <p style="float: left"><a href="/media/724/privacy policy.pdf" target="_new">Privacy Policy</a></p>
    <p style="float: left"><a href="/media/927/Sustainability Policy.pdf" target="_new">Sustainability Policy</a></p>
    <p style="float: left"><a href="/media/338/Equal Ops Policy.pdf" target="_new">Equal Opportunities Policy</a></p>
<p style="float:right">Designed by <a href="http://www.swan-solutions.com" target="_blank" title="Swan Solutions"><img src="/media/950/swan-solutions.jpg" alt="Swan Solutions" width="100" height="20" align="middle" /></a></p>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">



  var _gaq = _gaq || [];

  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-25186334-1']);

  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);



  (function() {

    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;

    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';

    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);

  })();



</script>
</body>
</html>

</asp:Content
```

>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to check is make sure all your relative URL's for images have a forwards slash at the beginning, e.g. /images/architecture.png - this will make sure it gets the image from the root image folder and not try to find it relative to the page.

Also, check in your CSS and/or javascript is there are any references to images and make sure they also have a forward slash at the beginning.

Comment: Still not worked. Any idea why my lightboxes dont display like they do in my designs pages and why this hover image isnt available unlike the rest?

Comment: Something I just noticed, it looks like that you are using a mixture of images from the media section (folder) and images folder, e.g. /media/57/architectureBLACK.png and images/architectureBLACK.png

Is this correct? for general site images (layout, navigation, etc) they should generally be in the images folder and other images (e.g. for content purposes) should be in media and controlled by content.

Other than that I'm not sure what else to suggest without having a look at your Umbraco install.

Comment: Should i just be using one way of refencing images?Its been completely fine for every other image in the site. I dont know if this is a clue but if i open the site in firefox and right click any of the images and press view image they all open up to show me the image. However, doing the same on "design and build" gives me the following error:

Comment: Server Error in '/' Application.
A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (&).
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (&).

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception...

Comment: ...can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[HttpException (0x80004005): A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (&).]
   System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig() +9023209
   System.Web.PipelineStepManager.ValidateHelper(HttpContext context) +59